# Where do I copy my VirtualHost directive in my Apache docker image?

Tags: django, apache, docker, virtualhost

I'm trying to Dockerize my Apache/Django project locally.  On my local machine (running Mac Sierra) I have this file (maps.conf) in my  /etc/apache2/other/ directory ...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName maps.example.com

    Alias /static /Library/WebServer/Documents/maps/maps/static
    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/maps/maps/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Next, add the following directory block
    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/maps/maps_project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess maps python-home=/Library/WebServer/Documents/maps/venv python-path=/Library/WebServer/Documents/maps
    WSGIProcessGroup maps
    WSGIScriptAlias / /Library/WebServer/Documents/maps/maps_project/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

I found this Apache docker file ...

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

Where am I supposed to copy my VirtualHost directive above so that my Apache docker image connects properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

It's at `/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, but you'll need to do more than just copying yours there because a) Apache won't know about it; and b) your macOS paths won't work.

#### Long version

[The Docker docs for the official Apache image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) show how to extract the main Apache config:

```
docker run --rm httpd:2.4 cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf > my-httpd.conf
```

Now you have a `my-httpd.conf` locally, outside the container.  Open it up and have a look - it is just a standard Apache config, and towards the bottom you'll see the usual:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

So now we can see both how to include a vhost config, and where to put it.

First, uncomment that `Include` line in your local copy of `my-httpd.conf` so that the vhosts config will actually be included.  We'll copy that edited version into the container, overwriting the original, so it will be used at runtime.

Now we need to update your existing vhosts config file (`maps.conf`) so it is suitable for use in the container.  The macOS-specific paths you're currently using in that file won't exist inside the container, so the file won't work as-is.

You can see the main Docroot in the main `my-httpd.conf` file:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
```

For simplicity let's put your content under that main Docroot, say in a dir called `maps/`.  Copy your `maps.conf` to a new file (say `my-vhosts.conf` in the same dir as `my-httpd.conf`), updating your macOS `/Library/WebServer/Documents/maps` paths with the container path `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/maps`.  I can't replicate your app/config, but for the sake of demonstration I used this super simple `my-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/maps"
</VirtualHost>
```

Next put it all together in the Dockerfile.  It needs to copy in the 2 new config files, as well as your actual content.  Note that you can't use a an absolute path for the *source* file in a `COPY` command, so you'll need to move or copy your local `maps/` content into the current directory first.

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY ./my-vhosts.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
COPY ./maps /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/maps
```

Now just build it and run it.  Again using the commands shown in the Docker docs for Apache:

```
docker build -t my-apache2 .
docker run -dit --name my-running-app -p 8080:80 my-apache2
```

Finally, for the sake of completeness, for local development where you might not want to keep recreating and running the image as you work on your app or tune your config files, you could map those things into the container as volumes, rather than just copy them in once at build-time.  That way you can work and see your changes live in the container.

Easiest approach for that would be to use `docker-compose`, and a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
    apache:
        image: httpd:2.4 
        container_name: apache
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./my-httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
            - ./my-vhosts.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
            - ./maps:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/maps
```

Then `docker-compose up` to run it.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! I had to make a few tweaks to use apache2.conf instead of httpd.conf but your post was exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is: your posted `VirtualHost directive` will not work inside the docker container because it is referencing your local machine directories: `/Library/WebServer/Documents/maps/maps/static` and `/Library/WebServer/Documents/maps/maps_project`

You will need to create a custom VirtualHost directive that references the path inside your docker container but not in your local machine.

Comment: I'm happy to do this.  Please list the Dockerfile I should use in your question.  I assume the standard Apache 2.4 Dockerfile has a common path.